# Parsing a web page with a tree structure

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

so I am trying to parse the following web page:[ this][1]. The web page is structured as a tree that I have fully expanded. Now, I have managed to open the expanded tree with BeautifulSoup like this:

```
soup =[]
soup.append(BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml'))
#print(soup[0].prettify())
```

but when the html structure appeared I was quite puzzled on the way to proceed. My aim ideally, is to scrape the name at the last leaf of the tree and the right above code. So for instance if you navigate in the web page linked and expand the tree for A -> A02-> A02B->A02BC->A02BC01->Losec and associated names (referral), then I would like to scrape "Losec and associated names" and A02BC01. Oof course doing the same for the rest of the tree.

The html structure looks as follows:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
        <link type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="https://ec.europa.eu/health/sites/health/themes/health/favicon.ico">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="NO-CACHE">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="creator" content="SANTE/DG/UNIT/B5">
        <meta name="description" content="Union Register of medicinal products">
        <meta name="date" content="15/09/2020">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Public Health, European Commission, European Union, EU, Union Register, Medicinal products">
        <meta name="reference" content="Union Register of medicinal products">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta property="og:description" content="Union Register of medicinal products">
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Union Register of medicinal products">
        <meta property="og:title" content="Public Health - European Commission">
        <meta property="og:type" content="website">
        <meta property="robots" content="follow,index">
        <meta property="revisit-after" content="15 Days">
        <title>Union Register of medicinal products - Public health - European Commission</title>
      
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../datatables/datatables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jstree/themes/default/style.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jstree/jstree.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/register_common.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Initialize script parameters.
            var exportTitle ="Centralised medicinal products for human use by ATC code";

            // Initialise the dataset.
            var dataSet = [
{"id":"A","parent":"#","text":"A - Alimentary tract and metabolism"},
{"id":"A02","parent":"A","text":"A02 - Drugs for acid related disorders"},
{"id":"A02B","parent":"A02","text":"A02B - Drugs for treatment of peptic ulcer"},
{"id":"A02BC","parent":"A02B","text":"A02BC - Proton pump inhibitors"},
{"id":"A02BC01","parent":"A02BC","text":"A02BC01 - omeprazole"},
{"id":"ho15861","parent":"A02BC01","text":"Losec and associated names (referral)","type":"pl"},
{"id":"A02BC02","parent":"A02BC","text":"A02BC02 - pantoprazole"},
{"id":"h515","parent":"A02BC02","text":"CONTROLOC Control (active)","type":"pl"},
{"id":"h518","parent":"A02BC02","text":"PANTECTA Control (withdrawn)","type":"pl"},
{"id":"h519","parent":"A02BC02","text":"PANTOLOC Control (active)","type":"pl"},
{"id":"h517","parent":"A02BC02","text":"PANTOZOL Control (active)","type":"pl"},
{"id":"ho15744","parent":"A02BC02","text":"Pantoprazole Bluefish (referral)","type":"pl"},
```

and continues:

```
</script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tree_atc.js"></script>
       
       <style type="text/css" media="all">
           @import url("../css/health.css");
           @import url("../css/europa.css");
           @import url("../css/register.css");
       </style>
   </head>

   <body>
       <!--
           First header section including the main topic selection, the EU logo and the search form.
       -->
       <header class="ecl-site-header" role="banner">
           <div class="ecl-site-switcher ecl-site-switcher--header">
               <ul id="ecl-site-switcher-header" class="ecl-site-switcher__list ecl-container">
                   <li class="ecl-site-switcher__option first"><a href="https://ec.europa.eu/commission/index_en" class="ecl-site-switcher__link ecl-link">Commission and its priorities</a></li>
                   <li class="ecl-site-switcher__option last ecl-site-switcher__option--is-selected">  <a href="https://ec.europa.eu/info/index_en" class="ecl-site-switcher__link ecl-link">Policies, information and services</a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>

           <div class="ecl-container ecl-site-header__banner">
               <a href="https://ec.europa.eu" class="ecl-logo" title="European Commission">
                   <span class="ecl-u-sr-only">European Commission</span>
               </a>
           </div>
       </header>

       <!--
           Second header section including the limited breadcrumb and the page main title.
       -->
       <div class="ecl-page-header">
           <div class="ecl-container">
               <nav class="ecl-breadcrumbs" aria-label="breadcrumbs">
                   <div class="item-list">
                       <ol class="ecl-breadcrumbs__segments-wrapper">
                           <li class="ecl-breadcrumbs__segment ecl-breadcrumbs__segment--first first"><a href="https://ec.europa.eu/index_en.htm" class="ecl-breadcrumbs__link">European Commission</a></li>
                           <li class="ecl-breadcrumbs__segment last"><a href="https://ec.europa.eu/info/live-work-travel-eu_en" class="ecl-breadcrumbs__link">Live, work, travel in the EU</a></li>
                       </ol>
                   </div>
               </nav>
               <div class="ecl-page-header__body">
                   <div class="support"><button class="buttonSupport" title="Contact Union Register support">Union Register support</button></div>                     
                   <div class="ecl-page-header__identity">Public Health - Union Register of medicinal products</div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>

       <!--
           Main content section. This is where the Union Register specific content will be displayed.
       -->
       <div id="mainContainer1" class="health-mainContainer">
           <div class="wrapper-fixed">
               <div class="ecl-container">
                   <h1 id="content-title">Centralised medicinal products for human use by ATC code</h1>
                   <button class="dt-button dtButtonHome" title="Back to Union Register homepage" id="home"><span></span></button>
                   <button class="dt-button dtButtonExpandAll" title="Expand entire list of ATC codes" id="expand_all"><span></span></button>
                   <button class="dt-button dtButtonCollapseAll" title="Collapse entire list of ATC codes" id="collapse_all"><span></span></button>
                   <div id="jstree_atc" class="jstree jstree-1 jstree-default" role="tree" aria-multiselectable="true" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="h941" aria-busy="false"><ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children jstree-no-dots" role="group"><li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1" aria-labelledby="A_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="A" class="jstree-node  jstree-open"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="A_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-hidden" role="presentation"></i>A - Alimentary tract and metabolism</a><ul role="group" class="jstree-children"><li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="2" aria-labelledby="A02_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="A02" class="jstree-node  jstree-open"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="A02_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-hidden" role="presentation"></i>A02 - Drugs for acid related disorders</a><ul role="group" class="jstree-children"><li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="3" aria-labelledby="A02B_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="A02B" class="jstree-node  jstree-open jstree-last"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="A02B_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-hidden" role="presentation"></i>A02B - Drugs for treatment of peptic ulcer</a><ul role="group" class="jstree-children"><li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="4" aria-labelledby="A02BC_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="A02BC" class="jstree-node  jstree-open jstree-last"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="A02BC_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-hidden" role="presentation"></i>A02BC - Proton pump inhibitors</a><ul role="group" class="jstree-children"><li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="5" aria-labelledby="A02BC01_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="A02BC01" class="jstree-node  jstree-open"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="A02BC01_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-hidden" role="presentation"></i>A02BC01 - omeprazole</a><ul role="group" class="jstree-children"><li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="6" aria-labelledby="ho15861_anchor" id="ho15861" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="ho15861_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://ec.europa.eu/health/documents/community-register/images/logo_file.png&quot;); background-size: auto; background-position: center center;"></i>Losec and associated names (referral)</a></li></ul></li><li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="5" aria-labelledby="A02BC02_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="A02BC02" class="jstree-node  jstree-open"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="A02BC02_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-hidden" role="presentation"></i>A02BC02 - pantoprazole</a><ul role="group" class="jstree-children"><li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="6" aria-labelledby="h515_anchor" id="h515" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="h515_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://ec.europa.eu/health/documents/community-register/images/logo_file.png&quot;); background-size: auto; background-position: center center;"></i>CONTROLOC Control (active)</a></li><li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="6" aria-labelledby="h518_anchor" id="h518" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="h518_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://ec.europa.eu/health/documents/community-register/images/logo_file.png&quot;); background-size: auto; background-position: center center;"></i>PANTECTA Control (withdrawn)</a></li><li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="6" aria-labelledby="h519_anchor" id="h519" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="h519_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://ec.europa.eu/health/documents/community-register/images/logo_file.png&quot;); background-size: auto; background-position: center center;"></i>PANTOLOC Control (active)</a></li><li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="6" aria-labelledby="h517_anchor" id="h517" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="h517_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://ec.europa.eu/health/documents/community-register/images/logo_file.png&quot;); background-size: auto; background-position: center center;"></i>PANTOZOL Control (active)</a></li><li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="6" aria-labelledby="ho15744_anchor" id="ho15744" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="ho15744_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://ec.europa.eu/health/documents/community-register/images/logo_file.png&quot;); background-size: auto; background-position: center center;"></i>Pantoprazole Bluefish (referral)
```

Is there a way to scrape what I would like?

Comment: Maybe the first structure is written in jave and the second html part is to specify the positioning of the java written code in the page? When inspecting the leaves I obtain: ```<a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="ho15861_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://ec.europa.eu/health/documents/community-register/images/logo_file.png&quot;); background-size: auto; background-position: center center;"></i>Losec and associated names (referral)</a>```

Comment: Do you have a URL that you can provide. its a bit easier to test out the actual output. From the information provided you need to look into the "text" field containing the "(referral)" if the condition is met, then the entire line needs to be printed.